# Being able to set the timeout on select() on a port file descriptor on the fly

Tags: c, unix, serial-port, posix, file-descriptor

Is there a way to change the timeout on select() on an FD that's opened for a serial port on the fly? Like, in `Thread1`, it's set to NULL which means it's going to block until there's any data on the FD. Now, I'd want to change its behavior such that `Thread2` sets a timeout on the `select` in `Thread1` which timesout after a specified timeout.

Is it in any way feasible?

Assuming here `Thread1` runs first so `select()` initially starts with no timeout and the timeout is then modified by `Thread2` as it runs later (while `Thread1` is still waiting on the `select()`)...

```
int timeout = 5;
struct timeval timeSpec = {timeout, 0};
void *pTimeout = NULL;    

void *Thread2(void *)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pTimeout = &timeSpec; // have select() timeout in 5 seconds from now on...
    }
}

void *Thread1(void *)
{
    fd_set fdset;
    
    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&fdset);
        FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
    
        ret = select (fd + 1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, pTimeout);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            // error handling
        }
        else if (ret == 0)
        {
            // timeout -- error handling
        }
        else
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(fd, &fdset))
            {
                bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, bytesToRead);  // blocking read call
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    // error handling
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Assuming here Thread1 runs first...and no racing happens for the sake of simplicity"* - what do you mean here? Both threads are in an infinite loop. What sequence of events would you want to observe? What racing does not happen? The threads do not share any other resource except `pTimeout`, which is only  written to by `Thread2`....

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, what problem are you trying to solve that would require something like this?

Comment: the first comment is about thread1 running first so initially the pTimeout is set to NULL and then i'd want to change the select() timeout from thread2

Comment: "change the select() timeout from thread2" - what do you mean by this? Please explain more clearly. You want to change it while `Thread1` is in the `select` waiting? Or just after the first `select` is over? Or before? It's unclear. You could write your expected sequence of actions by the two threads in chronological order to make it clearer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli this is an excerpt from my project and I didn't feel like including the rest of the details since they may not really be relevant. I'd mainly want to switch between changing the timeout to NULL and some value in thread1

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I want to change the select() timeout from `Thread2` while `Thread1` is waiting, correct...hence my assumption for `Thread1` running first to avoid any confusion

Comment: Can't change the timeout *while* the first thread is waiting. Unless you want to become insane with signals (e.g. signal thread 1 while it is waiting so it cancels the select, then change the timeout, then restart the select), but I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: If `thread1` 'manages' the `select` call then you can create a socket pair/pipe that can be used by the two threads to communicate various requests: e.g. "adjust the timeout".  `thread1` can just add the read end of the socket pair to the `fdset` being read from.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: @G.M. can you still modify the select()'s parameter while it's already blocked though? also doesn't socketpair work with sockets only?

Comment: @G.M. it seems that OP wants to change the timeout while thread 1 is still waiting inside `select`... so that doesn't look like an option.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli and xyf,  by using the pipe in this way the request from `thread2` will automatically cause the `select` call in `thread1` to return as data has been written to the 'write' end of the pipe on which it is listening.  Sorry if I haven't explained very well.

Comment: @G.M. oh, that's clever, makes sense. Though I'm not sure if that's what OP wants.

Comment: @G.M. could you please provide an example that may work? also with socketpair, what `type` are you using? are you saying that `select` returns as soon as fd is being written to no matter if it's already blocked or not?